# WooCommerce: Get $cart_item in price function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm using a custom function to change the style of the product price.

This is my actual function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', function( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    // stuff happens here
}, 10, 3 );
```

It works fine on product detail pages if I want some meta fields from the product.

I can get these meta fields if I use `global $product` and go from there.

The problem is, that `global $product` throws an error if used on the cart/checkout page.

So I'm using `is_product()` and `is_cart()` to check where I am.

But I couldn't figure out how to get the meta fields from a product in the cart.

I know, that I could use `$cart_item` like `$product`.
But it seems that there is no way to use that with `global`.

Is there any other way to get the cart item in the function above?

Comment: this filter is for product its self not for cart/checkout/mini cart etc. Once added to the cart the product can be accessed as $cart = WC()->cart; You can see examples here - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-cart-info-total-items-etc-from-cart-object/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WC()->cart` to get cart object. then you can loop it using `$cart->get_cart()` to get `cart_item`. try below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', function( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        $cart = WC()->cart; // Get cart
        if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {
            foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                // stuff happens here
            }
        }
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```